# javafx borderpane aligning in left and right space

Tags: java, javafx

I have `BorderPane` and 2 circles. One is added to left space of the `BorderPane` and second on right. I want to have space of 100 pixels between them. So I create `VBox` and I use `setPrefWidth(100)` on `HBox`. I struggle to move circles. Left circle to right and right circle to left so space between them is 100px. I don't want use padding, so it will be dynamically changing based on monitor resolution.

```
Circle centerCardCircle = new Circle(300);
centerCardCircle.setFill(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE);

Circle userCardCircle = new Circle(300);
userCardCircle.setFill(Color.DEEPSKYBLUE);

BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
borderPane.setLeft(centerCardCircle);
BorderPane.setAlignment(centerCardCircle, Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
borderPane.setRight(userCardCircle);
BorderPane.setAlignment(userCardCircle, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.setPrefWidth(100);
borderPane.setCenter(hbox);

Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] fully demonstrating the issue. What exactly is not working? The only problem statement you give is "_I struggle to move circles_"—what does that mean?

Comment: Sorry about that. It would be better to show it on the picture. Goal is have cricle on the right borderpane, other circle on the left. In the middle 100pixel Vbox and both circles to be near the VBox so visualy those circles would be 100pixel a part. With the code presented, space between them is much wider.

Comment: Well, it's still not clear what your end goal is, but the easiest solution is to use: `var box = new HBox(100, new Circle(300), new Circle(300));  box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);` (uses [this constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html#%3Cinit%3E(double,javafx.scene.Node...))). Then use the `HBox` as the root of your `Scene`.